# Is this function injective,surjective?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, exponential-function, absolute-value

I have a function:
$F:R\rightarrow R^+,f(x)=a ^{\lvert x\rvert},0<a<1$.
Is this function surjective,injective?I know,that function is injective if $f(x_1)=f(x_2) \Rightarrow x_1=x_2$.My function won't be injective,since both $a$ and $x$ are always positive.Is my judgement correct?I know a function is surjective if each element of the codomain $y\in R$ is the image of some element in the domain $x\in R^+$,I tried finding the inverse of the function but failed.What can I do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ f $ is not injective since

$$f(-1)=f(1)=a$$

$ f $ is not sutjective because

$$(\forall x\in \Bbb R) \; f(x)=e^{|x|\ln(a)}$$

with $$ \ln(a)<0$$
so,
$$(\forall x\in \Bbb R)\; f(x)\le 1$$
and if we take for example $ y=2 $, there will be no $ x\in \Bbb R $ such that
$f(x)=y$.

Comment: Thanks,I understand the injection.But why are we finding the derivative of $a ^{\lvert x\rvert}$?

Comment: @Tabris I did not speak about derivative .